# The role of "functions.php" in a WordPress site

Tags: php, wordpress

From what I understand, when developing a theme, `functions.php` gets included in every WordPress page and is supposed to contain all the themes logic. Wordpress themes do not have a real "installation" and so if, say, it uses a table called `my_theme_table`, then a piece of logic inside functions.php might be

```
if (my_theme_table is not in db) create my_theme_table;
```

I looked inside the `functions.php` of a theme I downloaded and it has over **6,000 lines**. Isn't this extremely inefficient to have "installation logic", class definitions, etc., being read over every time a page is loaded?

Can someone help clear this up for me? I came from an ASP.NET background and this seems so strange.

Comment: Welcome to Wordpress. Its a terrible mess and should not be seen as a good example of PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From what I understand, when developing a theme, `functions.php` gets included in every WordPress page and is supposed to contain all the themes logic.

A theme's functions file is included in every request, but it should not *contain all of the theme's logic*. How you organize your theme's non-template files is up to you, but you should avoid trying to jam all of your code in the functions file.

> I looked inside the `functions.php` of a theme I downloaded and it has over 6,000 lines.

Unfortunately it is very common for theme developers to just dump all of their code into the functions file and turn it into one big procedural nightmare. Don't take that as an example of how things should be done.

Organize your theme files like you would any other project. Personally I like to adhere to the [PSR standards](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/) when developing a theme. My functions file usually just contains a few constants, a [PSR-4 autoloader](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) and an initalization. For example:

```
// Const
define('MYPROJECT_VERSION', '1.0.3');
define('MYPROJECT_BUILD', 169);

// Autoloader (PSR-4)
// Adapted from https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-4-autoloader-examples.md
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    // Project namespace
    $prefix = 'MyProject\\';

    // Base directory for the namespace prefix
    $base_dir = __DIR__ . '/core/';

    // Does the class use the namespace prefix
    $len = strlen($prefix);
    if (strncmp($prefix, $class, $len) !== 0) {
        return;
    }

    // Get the relative class name
    $relative_class = substr($class, $len);

    // Replace the namespace prefix with the base directory, replace namespace
    // separators with directory separators in the relative class name, append
    // with .php
    $file = $base_dir . str_replace('\\', '/', $relative_class) . '.php';

    // If the file exists, require it
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        /** @noinspection PhpIncludeInspection */
        require $file;
    }
});

// Initialize
\MyProject\MyTheme::init();

// End of file
```

> Isn't this extremely inefficient to have "installation logic", class definitions, etc., being read over every time a page is loaded?

If you use an autoloader, only the classes you utilize will be included. If you are concerned about PHP needing to parse source files on every request in general, look into [OPCache](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.opcache.php).

Regarding "installation logic", you can use the `after_switch_themes` and `switch_themes` hooks for installation and un-installation respectively.

```
add_action('after_switch_theme', function() {
    // Install
});

add_action('switch_theme', function() {
    // Uninstall
});
```

Comment: If you are creating a small personal portfolio site, then you don't really need some complex file structure files, right?

Comment: @dingo_d Projects change and grow over time. If you take the time to plan out and organize your code you'll end up with something much less complex in the long run. Once you learn the standard and how to apply it, it isn't all that hard to setup, even for a small project.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is not related to Wordpress or functions.php, but to PHP itself. the file is included every time, but in a typical environment it will be read and compiled only once after a restart and then be cached with a bytecode-cache. Since PHP5.5  Zend Opimizer is part of PHP, before that APC was a very common tool for that.

So the the only problem remaining is the code that is executed each time.

Answer (score -1):

functions.php contains the functions that hooks on wordpress - it should not contain any class definition (this should be done in a custom plugin). In a MVC point of view, we could say that functions.php is your controller that links your templates (views) with your models (Wordpress Core, custom plugins).

Some reading : https://codex.wordpress.org/Functions_File_Explained

Answer (score -1):

Use WordPress' conditional tags, global variables, defines, class checks and the like. For instance like so:

```
<?php
// load helper functions - always
require_once get_stylesheet_directory() . '/inc/helper-functions.php';

// load admin functions - for back-end only
if ( is_admin() )
require_once get_stylesheet_directory() . '/inc/admin-functions.php';

// load WooCommerce functions - when WooCommerce is active
if ( in_array(
'woocommerce/woocommerce.php',
apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) )
)
require_once get_stylesheet_directory() . '/inc/woocommerce-functions.php';

// load SomeClass' functions - when class SomeClass is known
if ( class_exists( 'SomeClass' ) )
require_once get_stylesheet_directory() . '/inc/someclass-functions.php';

// load debug functions - when debugging
if ( defined( 'WP_DEBUG' ) && WP_DEBUG )
require_once get_stylesheet_directory() . '/inc/debug-functions.php';
```

You can also bail out when meeting certain criteria inside some function:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdev_143439_enqueue_scripts' );

function wpdev_143439_enqueue_scripts() {

if (
    ! is_single()
    || is_singular( 'my_cpt' )
    || (
        defined( 'NEVERSCRIPT' )
        && NEVERSCRIPT
    )
) {
    return;
}

// Enqueue some scripts here
}
```